# Attach w3wp process to Visual Studio 2010 debugger for IETester

Tags: w3wp.exe

Im trying to attach w3wp.exe process in Visual Studio 2010 for ASP.net MVC application.
It works fine on using normal IE browsers. But not working on using IETester (IE7).

Do any one of you faced similar issue?. Please share some light on how to overcome it.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rootcause of my issue is JSON.Stringify erroring out in IE7.
So used JSON.js plugin to overcome the issue.

Because of the above issue the debugger in WCF service dint fire.I'm good now.

Thanks.